# Javascript - Find all occurences of brackets in a string and replace the content depending on it's content

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace, find

I want to search all occurrences of `url()` in string and replace the content on the basis of it's content.

So for example there are are these different url-contents:

```
url("assets/images/pic.jpg")
url('assets/images/pic.jpg')
url("../images/pic.jpg")
url(../images/pic.jpg)
url('../images/pic.jpg')
url('http://website.com/images/pic.jpg')
```

and a link that should be inserted in front of the
url, depending on the content:

```
link = "file://dir/first/"
```

If there is `../` in front the url, it should be removed
and link should be in front of it.

And if there is a `http://` in front, all of the http-link should be removed,
except the fil at the end and the link should be inserted in front:

so following link should be transformed to:

```
url('http://website.com/images/pic.jpg')
url("file://dir/first/pic.jpg")
```

The Problem is, that sometimes the link is in between a `"`, a `'` or nothing.

I just know how to replace the `../-things`

```
response=response.replace(/url\(\'\.\.\//g, "url('"+link);
response=response.replace(/url\(\"\.\.\//g, 'url("'+link);
response=response.replace(/url\(\.\.\//g, "url("+link);
```

Does anybody know a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: did you wnat to touch the first two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this if you want to touch the first two statements.

```
string.replace(/(url\(['"]?)(?:\.\.\/|http:\/\/[^)]*\/)?/g, "$1" + link);
```

If you don't want to touch the first two then remove the optional quantifier `?` present at the last.

```
string.replace(/(url\(['"]?)(?:\.\.\/|http:\/\/[^)]*\/)/g, "$1" + link);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iW2kU7/2)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was searching for!